# Pixel Fonts and Websites (CSS + HTML)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm searching a way to render a super-pixel font. Which means I want the pixels to be really visible. Without anti-aliasing if you prefer.

There was a nice google font which I used, but the problem is that firefox still anti-aliase it.

Any clue would be appreciated, any example too.
I tried to use that font : https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Press+Start+2P
It renders well in any browser but when I integrate it in my own website, it doesn't render well.

Comment: could you provide us with screenshots? And of course please higlight the part which is problematic or not working as expected.

Comment: Vector fonts are always candidates to antialiasing -- if not in one combination browser/size/resolution, then it still may in another. I know that Press Start font (wasn't it inspired by original 8x8 Sinclair Spectrum fonts?); it's "just" another vector font, *not* a true "bitmap" font.

Comment: Ah -- a *true* "bitmap" font could be made with drawing rectangles on a canvas. But then you're pretty much on your own, with all those varying resolution and size limits.

Comment: Well that doesn't sound logical to me. Why fonts aren't rendered as they are ? For example in Firefox the font is anti-aliased and in chrome it is not.   
I found this : http://devpro.it/pixelfont/

Comment: Actually with a small size of 8px the font renders well. What I want is that when the font gets bigger, the browser should not ant-aliase it.

Comment: Why they are not rendered "as they are"? Implementing fonts as *vectors* was the greatest thing since lead type setting -- they "are" not pixels. As for why there are *differences* in font rendering, you have to discuss that with FF/Chrome's developers.

Comment: Well you're right. Vectors are amazing for deep pixels screens now. Thanks for the help anyway I guess I'll have to stay with my "kind of anti-aliased font" x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually setting the CSS Property `font-weight` to `normal` kind of fixes the thing when the font size is small enough. It seems that bootstrap was kind of messing with my font.

For example :

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="notify-on-message" />
    New Message
</label>
```

Was creating a blurred font. After applying `style="font-weight: normal;"` to the label the font was not blurred anymore, both in Firefox and Chrome.